# JS: как извлечь подстроку начиная с символа '='?

Tags: javascript, строки, подстрока

Передаю в переменную адреса страниц сайта:

```
var page = location;
var pageHref = page.toString();
```

Адреса имеют вид:

```
http://mysite.ru/?page=home
http://mysite.ru/?page=about
http://mysite.ru/?page=news
и т.д.
```

Как из подобных строк вытащить и передать в переменную то, что после знака '='?

Функции substr и substring, как я понял, работают с позициями вхождения подстроки в строку. А мне нужен не номер символа, начиная с которого вырезается подстрока, а сам символ, после которого.

Comment: в строке может быть только один знак `=`?

Comment: @Grundy, да, только один

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если нужно получить подстроку после последнего `=`, разбейте строку с `=` и берите последний элемент с помощью `pop()`:

```js
var s = 'http://mysite.ru/?page=home';
var res = s.split('=').pop();
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Функции [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) и [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) вполне походят в данной задаче. Им нужно просто передать индекс первого символа после знака `=`. Для определения индекса можно применить функцию [lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastindexof), которая возвращает индекс последнего вхождения:

```js
var s = 'http://mysite.ru/?page=home';
var res = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);
console.log(res);

var res = s.substr(s.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);
console.log(res);
```